# How can I compute the Schur complement in PETSc?

Tags: pde, linear-algebra, petsc

How can I compute the Schur complement:

$$ S = K_{bb} - K_{ba} K_{aa}^{-1} K_{ab} $$

where

$$ K=\begin{pmatrix} K_{aa} & K_{ab} \\ K_{ba} & K_{bb} \end{pmatrix} $$

(in some ordering) is a PETSc matrix (`Mat`)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is very expensive to compute the Schur complement of a matrix and very rarely needed in practice. PETSc highly recommends avoiding algorithms that need it. The Schur complement of a matrix (dense or sparse) is essentially always dense, so begin by:

- forming a dense matrix $K_{ba}$,
- also create another dense matrix $T$ of the same size.
- Then either factor the matrix $K_{aa}$  directly with `MatLUFactor()` or `MatCholeskyFactor()`, or use `MatGetFactor()` followed by `MatLUFactorSymbolic()` followed by `MatLUFactorNumeric()` if you wish to use and external solver package like SuperLU_Dist. Call the result `A`.
- Then call `MatMatSolve(A,Kba,T)`.
- Then call `MatMatMult(Kab,T,MAT_INITIAL_MATRIX,1.0,&S)`.
- Now call `MatAXPY(S,-1.0,Kbb,MAT_SUBSET_NONZERO)`.
- Followed by `MatScale(S,-1.0)`

For computing Schur complements like this it does not make sense to use the `KSP` iterative solvers since for solving many moderate size problems using a direct factorization is much faster than iterative solvers. As you can see, this requires a great deal of work space and computation so is best avoided. However, it is not necessary to assemble the Schur complement $S$ in order to solve systems with it. Use `MatCreateSchurComplement(Kaa,Kaa_pre,Kab,Kba,Kbb,&S)` to create a matrix that applies the action of `S` (using `Kaa_pre` to solve with `Kaa`), but does not assemble.

Alternatively, if you already have a block matrix $$ K = \begin{pmatrix} K_{aa} & K_{ab} \\ K_{ba} & K_{bb} \end{pmatrix} $$ (in some ordering), then you can create index sets (`IS`) isa and isb to address each block, then use `MatGetSchurComplement()` to create the Schur complement and/or an approximation suitable for preconditioning. Since $S$ is generally dense, standard preconditioning methods cannot typically be applied directly to Schur complements. There are many approaches to preconditioning Schur complements including using the SIMPLE approximation $ K_{bb} - K_{ba} \operatorname{diag}(K_{aa})^{-1} K_{ab} $ to create a sparse matrix that approximates the Schur complement (this is returned by default for the optional "preconditioning" matrix in `MatGetSchurComplement()`).

Another alternative is to interpret the matrices as differential operators and apply approximate commutator arguments to find a spectrally equivalent operation that can be applied efficiently (see the "PCD" preconditioners from Elman, Silvester, and Wathen). A variant of this is the least squares commutator, which is closely related to the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse, and is available in `PCLSC` which operates on matrices of type `MATSCHURCOMPLEMENT`.

Comment: At the risk of reopening a settled question, I think this answer is too pessimistic. I think computing a schur complement can be a reasonable thing to do in some circumstances (substructuring/domain decomposition in particular) and there are other algorithms that can compute them with lower time complexity than what's described here. See https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/28934 for inspiration.